# Unable to open solution in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

i came across this weird problem and don't seem to find a solution for it.
the problem is....

my OS crashed and i had to reinstall XP and VS 2005 again....but
when i tried to open my solution (which was created using visual studio 2005) in VS 2005 it gives me the following error:

```
The application for project 'D:\VSS\SomeSolution\SomeProj\SomeEntityLayer\SomeEntityLayer.csproj' is not installed.

Make sure the application for the project type (.csproj) is installed.
```

Please help

Comment: Have you installed all the VS2005 service packs?

Comment: what kind of projects do you have in your solution are you using? If you are using a project type eg: WCSF web module - which isnt based on the default VS templates, it could be due to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem,

Visual studio 2005 was not installed properly with the required components. 
Once i did that everything went perfect !

thanks any ways!!
tc : )

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the project exists in the location mentioned. I think it is something to do with the folder where your project is locatted.